# Moving a file(s) in Accurev Stream

Tags: accurev

I'd like to move files from one stream to another stream within Accurev. I do not want to move the files in my own workspace, then promote the moved files.

Please advise.

Comment: "move" as in moving a file from one directory to another, or "move" as in moving elements up or cross the stream hierarchy??

Answer (score 1):

I assume neither stream is a backing stream for the other; if it was you could just promote or update the files up/down the stream hierarchy.

Otherwise, you could try to Change Palette, though I'm not sure you can do that without a workspace.

See here: http://www.accurev.com/download/docs/4.6.1_books/WebHelp/Change_Palette.htm

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20121027042439/http://www.accurev.com/download/docs/4.6.1_books/WebHelp/Change_Palette.htm

Comment: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/accurev/en/latest/online/Content/AccuRev-OnLine-Help/Change_Palette.html